# How to do without communication processes in this function?

Tags: c++, process, mpi

I have a function main, the code in which I want to execute only 1 time (that is, only in 0 process), except for one line in which the multiStrassen function is called - I want to execute this line by all processes (0-7 processes). Is it possible to do this without communicating processes using MPI_Send and MPI_Recv? Can I do something easier? Because then I need to transfer a lot of complex data from 0 process to all other processes (which I do inside the multiStrassen function and would not want to do here in main, because my code eventually becomes unreadable). One line spoils everything...

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int WORLD_RANK, WORLD_SIZE;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WORLD_RANK);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WORLD_SIZE);

    ...    

    int dimensionNew = ...

    vector<vector<int>> matrixA = ...
    vector<vector<int>> matrixB = ...

    vector<vector<int>> matrixC1(dimensionNew, vector<int>(dimensionNew));
    clock_t start2, end2;

    start2 = clock();
    matrixC1 = multiStrassen(matrixA, matrixB, dimensionNew); //this line
    end2 = clock();

    double answer2 = ((double) end2 - start2) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    cout << "Strassen = " << answer2 << " sec." << endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to be able to use in ranks 1 to 7 data, which is needed by `multiStrassen`, without transferring it? Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I thought, maybe there are some global variables for all processes or something like that

Comment: If you run on a single node, then use OpenMP instead of MPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, It is necessary to specifically use the MPI (task condition)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, By the way, I have already implemented this algorithm using OpenMP. This is currently the fastest implementation. I want the MPI to beat OpenMP, that is, to make it even faster.

Comment: The philosopher Jagger once said "you can't always get what you want"

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, If it does not work out, then it’s also good. But worth a try. I have such a task.

Comment: OpenMP is a shared-memory paradigm where threads share the variables since they are in the same memory space. MPI is a distributed-memory paradigm where each rank has its own memory space and data exchanges are explicit. There is no magic at work here - you must tell MPI exactly what data, when, and where to transfer.

Comment: @HristoIliev, OK, thanks, I understand. Then I will take in a cycle from 0 process to all other 1-7 processes the data for the multiStrassen function

Comment: I’d use broadcast or scatter to distribute the data.

Comment: @HristoIliev, I will try this method too

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `MPI_Comm_rank` for having your process id:

```
int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
```

Then by checking this value, you can decide which parts of the code call or not to call:

```
if (rank == 0)
{
   // this code only is called by the rank-0 process
}
// this code is called by all of the processes
```

In addition, considering the fact that `multiStrassen(...)` is going to be executed on all processes, you need to provide its inputs (e.g. `matrixA`, `matrixB` and `dimensionNew`) either by sending them (from one process to every process) or by calculating them at each process.

Comment: Then it will be necessary to transfer data from process 0 to all the others, that is, it will be necessary to use MPI_Send / MPI_Recv. My question is how to avoid using them.

Comment: You have one method, i.e. `multiStrassen(...)` that is going to be executed on every process. This methods needs some inputs, e.g. `matrixA`. So these inputs should be either passed to EVERY process or calculated locally. Are you searching for anything else?